# Sum 1 column in a select of multiple columns

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

Im trying to sum() the quantity field on my select query grouping them by the date value but Sql keep giving me errors saying not al columns are grouped in my GroupBy but i only wantt o group them by Date

This is my query:

```
SELECT   Date, Clave_PDV, Che, Lin, Dish, Dish_Name, Type, 
sum(Quantity) as Quant, Price, Total, Tur, Tur_Name, Group, 
Group_Name, Pdv_Name, St_Pla, St_Che
FROM  Dish_Sales
GROUP BY Date
```

How can i Sum(Quantity) grouping them by Date?

Comment: `I only want to group them by date`, then how are you supposed to choose the values for the `Che` or `Lin`, for instance?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to display columns that are not part of aggregate.  Which row to display in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You would remove all the columns you do not want:

```
SELECT Date, sum(Quantity) as Quant
FROM Dish_Sales
GROUP BY Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum by date you should us e

```
SELECT   Date, sum(Quantity) as Quant
FROM  Dish_Sales
GROUP BY Date
```

Otherwise you should use the group by for all column not aggregated

```
SELECT   Date, Clave_PDV, Che, Lin, Dish, Dish_Name, Type, 
sum(Quantity) as Quant, Price, Total, Tur, Tur_Name, Group, 
Group_Name, Pdv_Name, St_Pla, St_Che
FROM  Dish_Sales
GROUP BY Date, Clave_PDV, Che, Lin, Dish, Dish_Name, Type, 
     Price, Total, Tur, Tur_Name, Group, 
      Group_Name, Pdv_Name, St_Pla, St_Che
```